# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Can We Use Model Binding Over jQuery AJAX Calls?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

If i have the following jQuery function (in an external file):

```
function getResults(field1, field2, field3) {
   $.get('/Search/GetResults', { id: field1, type: field2, blah: field3 }, function(data) {
      $('#target').html(data);
   });
}
```

Which essentially takes a bunch of fields from the form, sends them to an action method (which returns a PartialViewResult), and binds the result to a target div.

Here is that action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetResults(int id, int type, string blah)
{
   var model = repository.GetResults(id, type, blah);
   return PartialView("Results", model);
}
```

Is it possible to use model-binding here? E.g can we do this:

```
function getResults(someModel) {
   $.get('/Search/GetResults', { model: someModel }, function(data) {
      $('#target').html(data);
   });
}
```

And this:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetResults(SearchPreferences prefs)
{
   var model = repository.GetResults(prefs);
   return PartialView("Results", model);
}
```

Or should i construct a JSON object and pass that? Currently those values are retrieved via individual jQuery DOM calls:

```
var field1 = $('#field1').val();
var field2 = $('#field2').val();
```

**The goal is** to reduce/simplify jQuery code. I have all those calls to grab all the values, then i need to pass them all as parameters.

Ideally i'd like to just pass one object.

Any recommendations?

**EDIT**: Just realized i may be able to use the new **JSON Model Binding** feature in ASP.NET MVC 3. Reading up on it now... (feel free to answer in advance in the meantime).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC 3, YES! Check out [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx), from TheGu himself.

> ASP.NET MVC 3 now includes built-in
>   support for posting JSON-based
>   parameters  from client-side
>   JavaScript to action methods on the
>   server.  This makes it easier to
>   exchange data across the client and
>   server, and build rich JavaScript
>   front-ends.

Comment: lol, i just added that edit in and am reading the same post as we speak. :)

Comment: Nice... I do the same thing sometimes!

Comment: You may also want to check out http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Comment: Grats, glad I could "help". The new MVC upgrades in v3 are awesome. I can't wait to dig into the JSON model binding feature as well.

Comment: It was awesome. I still had to construct the JSON object which isn't a big deal, but i love how model binding "just works". The convention-based nature of MVC is arguably it's best feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a class that contains the properties that you are sending over, the default model binder will kick in and bind the data to that class. In your example, create a class:

```
public class SearchPreferences 
{
  public int id { get; set; }

  public int type { get; set; }

  public string blah { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your action it can be:

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetResults(SearchPreferences prefs)
{
   var model = repository.GetResults(prefs);
   return PartialView("Results", model);
}
```

They key is to have the names in your $.get data match the names in your SerachPreferences class.

Comment: yes, im aware of that - and i **do** have that class. But with this method i still need to pass all the individual parameters, which is what im trying to avoid.